# Best way to store a 'time' value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

My class needs two properties: `startTime` and `endTime`. What is the best class to use? I know there is NSDate, but I only need to store a specific time (something in between 00:00-23:59), I don't need a date. What is the most elegant solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSTimeInterval is probably good enough for this.

It stores a time value in seconds as a double.

Eg. 5 mins = 300.0

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most elegant solution, and what you want, is `NSTimeInterval`, that is the primitive type that `NSDate` is built on top.

`NSTimeInterval` is a typedef for `double`, and is a measurement of time in seconds. This primitive time type do not have any concept of a reference date. What `NSDate` do is to add this concept of reference date and anchor the 0.0 time at 1 January 2001 GMT. There is nothing that stops you from inventing your own *reference date* or *anchor*, like for example *"midnight of whatever day there is"*.

What you can do is to add two properties of the `NSTimeInterval` either as `startTime` and `endTime` and let them both use *midnight* as the reference. Or you could skip `endTime` and go for a `startTime` and `duration` combo.

Answer (score 0):

There's [`NSDateComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which "can also be used to specify a duration of time, for example, 5 hours and 16 minutes."

Answer (score 0):

The `NSDate` class is similar to the `DateTime` class in C#: both hold a date and time, but they can be independent of each other. In Cocoa, you would compare two NSDate classes:

```
//Create NSDate objects in the time format
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *startTimeString = @"00:00:00"; //0 seconds
NSString *endTimeString = @"00:00:52"; //52 seconds
NSDate *startTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startTimeString];
NSDate *endTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endTimeString];

//Compare the time
BOOL date1before2 = [startTime compare:endTime] == NSOrderedAscending;
```